# Calling SQL Loader From SQL Plus

Tags: oracle, sqlplus

I was wondering if there was a way I can execute a SQL Loader script from SQL Plus.

We are using Oracle 10g.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

An alternative technique may be to use an [external table](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14215/et_concepts.htm). There is no need to take your CSV (or whatever) file and load it in a separate step. Simply declare your external table in the correct format (this is almost identical to a SQL*Loader parfile, but wrapped in a `CREATE TABLE` statement) and you can issue a `SELECT` directly against it, once the file is in the right place. It will create `.BAD` and `.LOG` files, just like SQL*Loader for any records that can't be cast to the datatypes in the table. You could expect [better performance](http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0%3a%3a%3a%3aP11_QUESTION_ID:6611962171229) too. These days I would consider SQL*Loader to be for legacy apps only.

Comment: Just found out that this approach won't work for loading (C)LOBs. I guess I'll give @BenV's suggestion a try ...

Answer (score 6):

You should be able to run it via the `HOST` command:

```
SQL> host /path/to/ora/bin/sqlldr parfile=...
```